Question about irrationality of $\pi$
Based on my limited knowledge of math, there's two types of irrational numbers: 1) The 'normal' ones, which consist of a radical sign and a positive integer and 2) the 'fancy' ones, like $\pi$ or $e$
Now, I know that most numbers in the first type can be represented using a fast-converging infinite series with just integers in them. But, many infinite series for numbers in the second type use the first type in their infinite series. Intuitively, shouldn't there be some combination of numbers from the first type (not as an infinite series) which exactly equal to numbers from the second series? Because both of them are afterall irrational.
Why can we not express $\pi$ as some closed form combination of radicals and integers?

Remark: your "normal" number is really an "algebraic" number, those that are roots of some polynomial with real coefficients. The "fancy" ones are called transcendental. A normal number has a different definition.

But then $f(x) = (x-\pi)(x-e)$ has roots $\pi$ and $e$ too.

Algebraic numbers are the roots of polynomials with rational coefficients.

The algebraic numbers are a field, which means that a transcendental number like $\pi$ cannot be the finite sum or product of algebraic numbers.

I have no idea what that means. Can you explain it in layman's terms?

As @SeanRoberson says, you're looking at algebraic and transcendental numbers here. To be a bit more specific, $x$ is algebraic if it is the root of a polynomial whose coefficients are all integers. This includes $1$, $\frac12$, $\sqrt2$ and the roots of $x^5-x+1=0$ (which cannot be written as a combination of what you called normal numbers!). Real numbers that are not algebraic are called transcendental, and include $\pi$ and $e$. Transcendentals we find "in the wild" (such as $\pi$ and $e$) are notoriously difficult to deal with - we still don't know if $\pi+e$ is transcendental!)

One other interesting thing about the set of algebraic numbers is that it is countable; which means we can label every algebraic number with a natural number. The same is not true of transcendental numbers. The Wikipedia article on algebraic numbers is a pretty good introduction to all of this.

Thank you @MartinR, I misspoke on the definition.

In lay terms, mathematicians have proved that given two irrational numbers that are the roots of integer polynomials, their sum and their product are also roots of integer polynomials. The proof isn't hard but it's too long to provide here. See the wikipedia post on algebraic numbers.
It's known that $\pi$ is not the root of an integer polynomial. The proof is quite hard. See the wikipedia page on transcendental numbers.
It follows from those two facts that $\pi$ is not a
"closed form combination of radicals and integers".

I think you just want an intuitive explanation rather than all the terminology.
An irrational number cannot be expressed as a ratio of integer constants, like $\frac{1}{2}$ is a rational number, but $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be expressed as a ratio of any two integers so it is irrational. There is no such $\frac{x}{y}$ that equals $ \sqrt{2} $ where $x $ and $y$ are integers.
A transcendental number is an irrational number that cannot be expressed through a non-zero polynomial with integer coefficients.
Consider $x^2 - 2 = 0$, a one-degree polynomial. Well $x = \pm\sqrt{2}$, so $\sqrt{2} $ is not transcendental.
But there's no such equivalent with $\pi$.
